# Facebook SDK: WebDialog authorization asks user name and password twice (once for read, once for publish)

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am developing on Android and I am using Facebook SDK version 3.0.2.

When there is a Facebook app present, then it logs in through Facebook app and when there is no Facebook app present, web dialog pops-up and asks for the user name and the password. So this is a case where no Facebook app is installed and web dialog shows up.

```
public static String[] PERMISSIONS_READ = new String[] { "read_stream"};
public static String[] PERMISSIONS_WRITE = new String[] { "publish_stream"};

Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
            if (openRequest != null) {
                openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
                openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS_READ));
                openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                session.openForRead(openRequest);
            }
```

session.openForRead() opens a web dialog asking for the user name and the password.
Since only read permissions are granted, I call another request for publish permissions:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
            if(session != null) {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS_WRITE));
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        }
```

session.requestNewPublishPermissions() brings up another Webview dialog asking for the user name and the password.

So in the end, user inputs the same user name & password twice! Can we avoid the second webview dialog asking for the same user name and the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Facebook-sdk version 3.5 solved the problem.